# Selecting in PSE

Tags: adobe-photoshop

What does this message mean and how do I work around it in Photoshop elements?

I want to select part of an image with the Lasso Tool.

"Warning: No pixels are more than 50% selected. The selection edges will not be visible."

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It means that all the pixels you selected have less than 50% opacity, and Photoshop draws the selection edges around those that have more.

What it *also* means is, you still have some pixels selected, but you can't see which ones, because the border is not visible. Try moving the selection around (or doing whatever you intended to do with it) and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have made a selection in the image, while working on the wrong layer. I make this mistake sometimes as well.